# How to add common header for each request (Swagger and Swashbuckle)

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I use Swashbuckle version 5.6 and .NET Framework. But my authorization is on the side server (another web API project only for authorization).
I would like to provide for my users a simple way to add an auth token for each request on the swagger UI. Currently, I can add the token or other additional headers via a Chrome extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)
But this is not obviously for users. I prefer to have all in one instrument without Chrome extensions. Is there a better way?

### UPDATE

So, it seems I have formulated my question not correctly. I'm going to fix it by adding new details. First, I would like to show what exactly I need. Please, see the screen of the [example](https://offleaseonly.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index) of the swagger's Authorization pop-up:
[image]

I'm trying to do for this the following:

1. Implement `IOperationFilter`

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.security == null)
        {
            operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
        }

        var test = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
        test.Add("test", new List<string>
        {
            "field1",
        });
        operation.security.Add(test);
    }
}
```

2. add this to my swagger configuration:

```
public static void Register()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
       
            c.RootUrl(ResolveBasePath);
            c.PrettyPrint();
            c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
            c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {              
            c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
        });
}
```

As the result I see the changes, but it's something strange. Yes, I see appeared authorization sign:

[image]

But if I click by it, I see this empty window:

[image]

I completely don't understand how the settings

```
var test = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
        test.Add("test", new List<string>
        {
            "field1",
        });
        operation.security.Add(test);
```

are binding with the window. Please, help.

Comment: Swagger UI has a place for auth, see the Authorize button on these examples:  http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index   https://offleaseonly.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Comment: Here is an article:  [Swagger - Security schema for protected APIs](https://karatejb.blogspot.com/2020/08/aspnet-core-swagger-security-schema-for.html) , which is about how to let user keyin Bearer token or Basic authentication on Swagger UI. Though its on ASP.NET Core, it should be in the same way on .NET framework.